# Flutter publish video stream to rtmp server

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, publish, rtmp

I got a Flutter app that get a stream of images from a websocket, like that :

```dart
stream?.stream.listen((message) {
   try {
     VideoUtil.saveImageFileToDirectory(message as Uint8List, 'image_$frameNum.jpg');
     frameNum++;
   } catch (e) {
     log('error decoding image');
   }
}
```

And i need to send those images as a video to a rtmp server. Is that possible and how can I acheived that.
I find packages like that :

- https://pub.dev/packages/rtmp_publisher
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rtmp_publisher
- https://pub.dev/packages/camera_with_rtmp

But I for what I understand it only stream the camera from the device like in facetime or zoom or ect

So is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for any clue in advance !

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess you can dig deep into ffmpeg and their commands.

On the desktop, you can simply your local file via command like: `ffmpeg -re -i ./source.flv -c copy -f flv -y rtmp://localhost/live/livestream`

There's a [ffmpeg wrapper for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter)

I've worked with it, but not in a streaming context. It's really flexible package even if some ffmpeg's plugin are missing you could build it manually. Maybe there will be some platform limitation for streaming output.

Anyway, I'll hope that it's help.

Comment: Ok thanks I will dig in it. But do you think this package ( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg ) can do the same thing ? I already have it in my project to make an output video with a bunch of image at the end of the process

Comment: @un-cafeinoman, as far i know[ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) is successor of [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg). And yep, it's the same thing from the same authors, but maybe will be better to upgrade to ffmpeg_kit_flutter cuz flutter_ffmpeg was discounted.

Comment: Ok thanks I will do that tho !!! And do you have any idea on how to send my stream of picture to rtmp server without making a video out of them ?